# Parsing an xml file correctly in perl

Tags: xml, perl, csv

I have a xml results file (gzipped) that I want to output as a nice tab-separated table.

I came up with a script that should do that job (code see below).

BUT: When some of the sections in the file, e.g. `Hamap`, are not present, then the table is shifted and no hyphen is printed when the field should be empty. How do I have to modify the script so that fields that are absent are also outputted as empty?

I can post two examples of my xml file in case you wish!

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use IO::Compress::Gzip;

my $input_file  = $ARGV[0]; 
my $output_file = "$ARGV[0]".".tsv";
$output_file =~ s/\.gz//;
my $i = 0;
my $query; my %annotation;

open (IN,"gzip -dc $input_file |") or die "\nCould not open $input_file\n";


while (<IN>) {
    if ( $_ =~ /\<xref desc=\"(.*)\" db=\"(.*)\" id=\"(.*)\" name=\"(.*)\"\/\>/) {

        $query = $3;
        $annotation{$query}{"order"}            = $i;
        $annotation{$query}{"Pfam"}             = "-";
        $annotation{$query}{"TIGRFAM"}          = "-";
        $annotation{$query}{"Gene3D"}           = "-";
        $annotation{$query}{"PANTHER"}          = "-";
        $annotation{$query}{"ProSiteProfiles"}  = "-";
        $annotation{$query}{"Hamap"}            = "-";
        $annotation{$query}{"SUPERFAMILY"}      = "-";
        $annotation{$query}{"PRINTS"}           = "-";
        $annotation{$query}{"PIRSF"}            = "-";
        $annotation{$query}{"SMART"}            = "-";
        $annotation{$query}{"GO_BIO"}           = "-";
        $annotation{$query}{"GO_MOL"}           = "-";
        $annotation{$query}{"GO_CEL"}           = "-";
        $annotation{$query}{"IPRO"}             = "-";
        $annotation{$query}{"pathway"}          = "-";
        $annotation{$query}{"CDD"}              = "-";
        $annotation{$query}{"MobiDBLite"}       = "-";


        $i++;


    } elsif ($_ =~ /\<xref/){
                if ($_ =~ /id=\"(.*)\"/){
                 $query=$1;
                 $annotation{$query}{"order"}            = $i;
                $annotation{$query}{"Pfam"}              = "-";
                $annotation{$query}{"TIGRFAM"}           = "-";
                $annotation{$query}{"Gene3D"}            = "-";
                $annotation{$query}{"PANTHER"}           = "-";
                $annotation{$query}{"ProSiteProfiles"}   = "-";
                $annotation{$query}{"Hamap"}             = "-";
                $annotation{$query}{"SUPERFAMILY"}       = "-";
                $annotation{$query}{"PRINTS"}            = "-";
                $annotation{$query}{"PIRSF"}             = "-";
                $annotation{$query}{"SMART"}             = "-";
                $annotation{$query}{"GO_BIO"}            = "-";
                $annotation{$query}{"GO_MOL"}            = "-";
                $annotation{$query}{"GO_CEL"}            = "-";
                $annotation{$query}{"IPRO"}              = "-";
                $annotation{$query}{"pathway"}           = "-";
                $annotation{$query}{"CDD"}               = "-";
                $annotation{$query}{"MobiDBLite"}        = "-";


                $i++;

                }


    } elsif ( $_ =~ /\<signature ac=\"(PF.*)\" desc=\"(.*)\" name=\"(.*)\">/ ) {                # Pfam 
            if ($annotation{$query}{"Pfam"} eq "-"){
                $annotation{$query}{"Pfam"} = "$1: $2";
        }else{
                $annotation{$query}{"Pfam"} .= "; $1: $2";
            } 

    } elsif ( $_ =~ /\<signature ac=\"(TIGR.*)\" desc=\"(.*)\" name=\"(.*)\">/ ) {              # TIGRFAM
        if ($annotation{$query}{"TIGRFAM"} eq "-"){
                $annotation{$query}{"TIGRFAM"} = "$1: $2";
        }else{
                $annotation{$query}{"TIGRFAM"} .= "; $1: $2";
            } 

    } elsif ( $_ =~ /\<signature ac=\"(G3DSA:.*)\">/ ) {                                        # Gene3D
        if ($annotation{$query}{"Gene3D"} eq "-"){
                $annotation{$query}{"Gene3D"} = "$1";
            }else{
            $annotation{$query}{"Gene3D"} .= "; $1";
            } 

    } elsif ( $_ =~ /\<signature ac=\"(PTHR.*)\" name=\"(.*)\"\>/ ) {                           # PANTHER
        if ($annotation{$query}{"PANTHER"} eq "-"){
                $annotation{$query}{"PANTHER"} = "$1: $2";
        }else{
                $annotation{$query}{"PANTHER"} .= "; $1: $2";
            } 

    } elsif ( $_ =~ /\<signature ac=\"(PS.*)\" desc=\"(.*)\">/ ) {                              # ProSiteProfiles
        if ($annotation{$query}{"ProSiteProfiles"} eq "-"){
                $annotation{$query}{"ProSiteProfiles"} = "$1: $2";
        }else{
                $annotation{$query}{"ProSiteProfiles"} .= "; $1: $2";
            } 

    } elsif ( $_ =~ /\<signature ac=\"(MF.*)\" desc=\"(.*)\" name=\"(.*)\">/ ) {                # Hamap
        if ($annotation{$query}{"Hamap"} eq "-"){
                $annotation{$query}{"Hamap"} = "$1: $2";
        }else{
                $annotation{$query}{"Hamap"} .= "; $1: $2";
            } 

    } elsif ( $_ =~ /\<signature ac=\"(SSF.*)\" name=\"(.*)\">/ ) {                             # SUPERFAMILY
        if ($annotation{$query}{"SUPERFAMILY"} eq "-"){
                $annotation{$query}{"SUPERFAMILY"} = "$1: $2";
            }else{
                $annotation{$query}{"SUPERFAMILY"} .= "; $1: $2";
            } 

    } elsif ( $_ =~ /\<signature ac=\"(PR.*)\" desc=\"(.*)\" name=\"(.*)\"\>/ ) {               # PRINTS
        if ($annotation{$query}{"PRINTS"} eq "-"){
                $annotation{$query}{"PRINTS"} = "$1: $2";
        }else{
                $annotation{$query}{"PRINTS"} .= "; $1: $2";
            } 

    } elsif ( $_ =~ /\<signature ac=\"(PIRSF.*)\" name=\"(.*)\">/ ) {                           # PIRSF
        if ($annotation{$query}{"PIRSF"} eq "-"){
                $annotation{$query}{"PIRSF"} = "$1: $2";
        }else{
                $annotation{$query}{"PIRSF"} .= "; $1: $2";
            } 

    } elsif ( $_ =~ /\<signature ac=\"(SM.*)\" desc=\"(.*)\" name=\"(.*)\"\>/ ) {               # SMART
        if ($annotation{$query}{"SMART"} eq "-"){
                $annotation{$query}{"SMART"} = "$1: $2";
        }else{
                $annotation{$query}{"SMART"} .= "; $1: $2";
            }

    } elsif ( $_ =~ /\<signature ac=\"(cd.*)\" desc=\"(.*)\" name=\"(.*)\"\>/ ) {               # CDD
        if ($annotation{$query}{"CDD"} eq "-"){
                $annotation{$query}{"CDD"} = "$1: $2";
        }else{
                $annotation{$query}{"CDD"} .= "; $1: $2";
            }

    } elsif ( $_ =~ /\<signature ac=\"(mobidb-lite.*)\" desc=\"(.*)\" name=\"(.*)\"\>/ ) {      # MobiDBLite
        if ($annotation{$query}{"MobiDBLite"} eq "-"){
                $annotation{$query}{"MobiDBLite"} = "$1: $2";
        }else{
                $annotation{$query}{"MobiDBLite"} .= "; $1: $2";
            }

    } elsif ( $_ =~ /\<go-xref category="BIOLOGICAL_PROCESS" db="GO" id="(GO:.*)" name="(.*)"\/>/ ) {
        if ($annotation{$query}{"GO_BIO"} eq "-"){
                $annotation{$query}{"GO_BIO"} = "$1: $2";
        }else{
                $annotation{$query}{"GO_BIO"} .= "; $1: $2";
            } 

    } elsif ( $_ =~ /\<go-xref category="MOLECULAR_FUNCTION" db="GO" id="(GO:.*)" name="(.*)"\/>/ ) {
        if ($annotation{$query}{"GO_MOL"} eq "-"){
                $annotation{$query}{"GO_MOL"} = "$1: $2";
        }else{
                $annotation{$query}{"GO_MOL"} .= "; $1: $2";
            } 

    } elsif ( $_ =~ /\<go-xref category="CELLULAR_COMPONENT" db="GO" id="(GO:.*)" name="(.*)"\/>/ ) {
        if ($annotation{$query}{"GO_CEL"} eq "-"){
                $annotation{$query}{"GO_CEL"} = "$1: $2";
        }else{
                $annotation{$query}{"GO_CEL"} .= "; $1: $2";
            } 

    } elsif ( $_ =~ /\<pathway-xref db="(.*)" id="(.*)" name="(.*)"\/>/ ) {
        if ($annotation{$query}{"pathway"} eq "-"){
                $annotation{$query}{"pathway"} = "$1-$2: $3";
        } elsif ($annotation{$query}{"pathway"} =~ /$2/) {
            next;
        }else{
                $annotation{$query}{"pathway"} .= "; $1-$2: $3";
            } 



    } elsif ( $_ =~ /\<entry ac="(IP.*)" desc="(.*)" name="(.*)" type="(.*)">/ ) {
        if ($annotation{$query}{"IPRO"} eq "-"){
                $annotation{$query}{"IPRO"} = "$1: $2";
        } elsif ($annotation{$query}{"IPRO"} =~ /$1/) {
            next;
        }else{
                $annotation{$query}{"IPRO"} .= "; $1: $2";
            } 

    } elsif ( $_ =~ /\<\/protein\-matches\>/ ) {

    }

}
close (IN);

open (OUT, ">$output_file") or die "\nCould not open $output_file\n";
print OUT "Query\tInterPro Entry\tInterPro: pathways\tInterPro: GO terms - Molecular Function\tInterPro: GO terms - Biological Process\tInterPro: GO terms - Cellular Component\t";
print OUT "InterPro: Pfam\tInterPro: TIGRFAM\tInterPro: PANTHER\tInterPro: ProSiteProfiles\tInterPro: Hamap\t";
print OUT "InterPro: PIRSF\tInterPro: Gene3D\tInterPro: SUPERFAMILY\tInterPro: PRINTS\tInterPro: SMART\tInterPro: CDD\tInterPro: MobiDBLite\n";

foreach my $query (sort {$annotation{$a}{"order"} <=> $annotation{$b}{"order"}} keys %annotation ) {
    print OUT $query,"\t",$annotation{$query}{"IPRO"},"\t",$annotation{$query}{"pathway"},"\t",$annotation{$query}{"GO_MOL"},"\t",$annotation{$query}{"GO_BIO"},"\t",$annotation{$query}{"GO_CEL"},"\t";
    print OUT $annotation{$query}{"Pfam"},"\t",$annotation{$query}{"TIGRFAM"},"\t",$annotation{$query}{"PANTHER"},"\t";
    print OUT $annotation{$query}{"ProSiteProfiles"},"\t",$annotation{$query}{"Hamap"},"\t",$annotation{$query}{"PIRSF"},"\t";
    print OUT $annotation{$query}{"Gene3D"},"\t",$annotation{$query}{"SUPERFAMILY"},"\t",$annotation{$query}{"PRINTS"},"\t";
    print OUT $annotation{$query}{"SMART"},"\t",$annotation{$query}{"CDD"},"\t",$annotation{$query}{"MobiDBLite"},"\n";
}

close (OUT);


exit 1;
```

UPDATE: Here are two example files, the first one works as expected, but the second does not work properly (there is a shift in the fields).

[example 1](https://pastebin.com/c73whyqk)

[example 2](https://pastebin.com/nh08bSBB)

Desired output of example 2:

```
Query   InterPro Entry  InterPro: pathways  InterPro: GO terms - Molecular Function InterPro: GO terms - Biological Process InterPro: GO terms - Cellular Component InterPro: Pfam  InterPro: TIGRFAM   InterPro: PANTHER   InterPro: ProSiteProfiles   InterPro: Hamap InterPro: PIRSF InterPro: Gene3D    InterPro: SUPERFAMILY   InterPro: PRINTS    InterPro: SMART InterPro: CDD   InterPro: MobiDBLite
id_10005" name="id_10005    -   -   -   -   -   PF13614: AAA domain -   PTHR13696:SF85: SUBFAMILY NOT NAMED; PTHR13696: FAMILY NOT NAMED    -   G3DSA:3.40.50.300   SSF52540: P-loop containing nucleoside triphosphate hydrolases  -   -   -   -   -   mobidb-lite: consensus disorder prediction; mobidb-lite: consensus disorder prediction
id_10004" name="id_10004    -   -   -   -   -   PF13614: AAA domain -   PTHR13696:SF86: SUBFAMILY NOT NAMED; PTHR13696: FAMILY NOT NAMED    -   G3DSA:3.40.50.300   SSF52540: P-loop containing nucleoside triphosphate hydrolases  -   -   -   -   cd02042: ParA   -
```

Comment: Why don't you use a XML parser like [XML::LibXML](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::LibXML) and then implement your processing in the DOM domain? For tabulated output I would recommend [Text::Table](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::Table). It would also help to see an example of your input data and the expected output.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know enough about this data to know what the problem is. I don't even understand your description of what is wrong with the bad output. Could you please explain it in simpler words. "I'm expecting to see 'foo' in column X, but instead I'm seeing 'bar'". Thanks.

Comment: One useful debugging aid would be to use Data::Dumper to display the contents of `%annotation` after you've finished parsing the input file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is quite long, so my answer will only present the gist of the idea with a few example items processed. But it should give you a starting point how to process the other items in your XML data.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::LibXML;

# XML namespace
use constant DEFAULT_XMLNS => 'http://www.ebi.ac.uk/interpro/resources/schemas/interproscan5';

my $doc;
eval {
    $doc = XML::LibXML->load_xml(IO => \*STDIN);
};
die "XML parser error: $@\n"
    if $@;

# initialize XPath context
# NOTE: all nodes without NS must use default: prefix!
my $xpc = XML::LibXML::XPathContext->new();
$xpc->registerNs('default', DEFAULT_XMLNS);

# Signature processors - code
sub processor_just_primary {
    my($protein, $key, $primary) = @_;
    push(@{ $protein->{$key} }, $primary);
}
sub processor_primary_and_first_attr {
    my($protein, $key, $primary, $attrs) = @_;
    push(@{ $protein->{$key} }, "${primary}: " . $attrs->[0]);
}

# Signature processors - map key, "ac" identifier, attributes, code
my %signature_processors = (
    Gene3D  => {
        id   => qr/^G3DSA:(.+)/,
        attr => [],
        code => \&processor_just_primary,
    },
    Hamap   => {
        id   => qr/^(MF.+)/,
        attr => [ qw{desc name} ],
        code => \&processor_primary_and_first_attr,
    },
    PANTHER => {
        id   => qr/^(PTHR.+)/,
        attr => [ qw{name} ],
        code => \&processor_primary_and_first_attr,
    },
    TIGRFAM => {
        id   => qr/^(TIGR.+)/,
        attr => [ qw{desc name} ],
        code => \&processor_primary_and_first_attr,
    },
);

my @proteins;
foreach my $protein_node ($xpc->findnodes('//default:protein', $doc)) {
    # search <xref> node downwards from <protein> node
    my @xrefs  = $xpc->findnodes('./default:xref', $protein_node)
        or die "Can't find xref node for protein " . $protein_node->toString() . "\n";
    my $id     = $xrefs[0]->getAttribute('id')
        or die "Can't get attribute 'id' for protein " . $xrefs[0]->toString() . "\n";

    # initialize new protein
    # NOTE: a key with an undefined value means "not found" -> empty column
    my %protein  = map { ($_ => undef) } keys %signature_processors;
    $protein{ID} = $id;
    push(@proteins, \%protein);

    # fill protein with signature matches - searching nodes downwards from <protein/matches> node
    foreach my $signature ($xpc->findnodes('./default:matches//default:signature', $protein_node)) {
        my($attr_ac) = $signature->getAttribute('ac')
            or die "Can't get attribute 'ac' for XML node " . $signature->toString() . "\n";

        while (my($key, $processor) = each %signature_processors) {
            my($primary)  = ($attr_ac =~ $processor->{id})
                or next;

            # additional attributes
            my @attrs;
            foreach my $attr (@{ $processor->{attr} }) {
                my($value) = $signature->getAttribute($attr)
                    or die "Can't get attribute '${attr}' for XML node " . $signature->toString() . "\n";
                push(@attrs, $value);
            }

            # call processor
            $processor->{code}->(\%protein, $key, $primary, \@attrs);
        }
    }
}

my @key_order = qw(
    TIGRFAM
    Hamap
    PANTHER
    Gene3D
);

sub dump_row(@) {
    print join("\t", @_), "\n";
}

dump_row('ID', @key_order);
foreach my $protein (@proteins) {
    my @columns =
        map { $_ ? join('; ', @{ $_ }) : '-' } # handle empty columns
        @{ $protein }{@key_order};

    dump_row($protein->{ID}, @columns);
}

exit 0;
```

Test output for example 1:

```
$ perl dummy.pl <Downloads/c73whyqk.txt 
ID      TIGRFAM Hamap   PANTHER Gene3D
id_10002        -       -       -       -
id_10001        TIGR00621: ssb: single-stranded DNA-binding protein     MF_00984: Single-stranded DNA-binding protein.  PTHR10302:SF0: SINGLE-STRANDED DNA-BINDING PROTEIN, MITOCHONDRIAL; PTHR10302: SINGLE-STRANDED DNA-BINDING PROTEIN      2.40.50.140
id_10003        -       -       PTHR34107: FAMILY NOT NAMED     3.90.1570.10
```

Test output for example 2:

```
$ perl dummy.pl <dummy.xml
ID      TIGRFAM Hamap   PANTHER Gene3D
id_10005        -       -       PTHR13696:SF85: SUBFAMILY NOT NAMED; PTHR13696: FAMILY NOT NAMED        3.40.50.300
id_10004        -       -       PTHR13696:SF86: SUBFAMILY NOT NAMED; PTHR13696: FAMILY NOT NAMED        3.40.50.300
```

---

**BONUS CODE:** as the question is also tagged with [csv](/questions/tagged/csv) I'll add the changes required to generate CSV output:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Text::CSV;
use XML::LibXML;

# ... the main code is left unchanged ...

my $csv = Text::CSV->new()
    or die "Cannot use CSV: " . Text::CSV->error_diag() . "\n";
$csv->eol("\n");

sub dump_row(@) {
    $csv->print(\*STDOUT, \@_);
}

dump_row('ID', @key_order);
foreach my $protein (@proteins) {
    my @columns =
        map { $_ ? join('; ', @{ $_ }) : '' } # handle empty columns
        @{ $protein }{@key_order};

    dump_row($protein->{ID}, @columns);
}

exit 0;
```

---

**UPDATE 2:** it turns out that loading the TSV version of the original code can lead to problem when your CSV importer doesn't have an option to disable `,` (comma) and `;` (semicolon) as separators. The original code should therefore be rewritten to use [Text::CSV](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV) instead, which does proper quoting and therefore avoids such problems.

I've also added some sanity check code for `@key_order` vs. `%signature_processors`.

```perl
# sanity checks
die "\@keyorder has keys not in \%signature_processors!\n"
    if grep { not exists $signature_processors{$_} } @key_order;
{
    my %keys = map { ($_ => 1) } @key_order;
    die "\%signature_processors has keys not in \@keyorder!\n"
        if grep { not exists $keys{$_} } keys %signature_processors;
}

my $csv = Text::CSV->new({
    binary   => 1,
    eol      => "\n",
    # Select the output format by uncommenting *one* of the following
    #sep_char => ',', # CSV - comma separated values
    sep_char => "\t", # TSV - TAB separated values
})
    or die "Cannot use CSV: " . Text::CSV->error_diag() . "\n";

sub dump_row(@) {
    $csv->print(\*STDOUT, \@_);
}
```

Comment: Added output for example 1 too.

Comment: Hmm, the idea is correct, but the results are incorrect. I think there is a bug in the XPath processing...

Comment: There will hopefully be a day when I'll understand XML and XPath... Fixed.

Comment: After contemplating the given XML data a bit, I have restructured the main loop to loop over `<protein>` nodes and look downwards for a `<xref>` node (for the ID) and `<matches>...<signature ...>` nodes.

Comment: I am having some trouble with the code for the `tsv` separated output. For the `csv` code, I am using the same "main code", and I am getting the desired output. However, when using the same "main code" with the `tsv` code, some columns are not filled up and some cells are not in the correct place. I can provide you with the code + example if you wish! Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried `my $csv = Text::CSV->new({ binary => 1, eol => "\n", sep_char => "\t" })`?

Comment: This also leads to weird results (number of cells than expected). My best guess is that there are some characters in my input that are not supported?

Comment: I don't quite understand your problem. How can there be "missing columns" when `keys %signature_processors == @key_order`? Maybe you have added a key in one of them that is missing in the other one? The output code at the end always generates `@key_order + 1` columns for every row. Or maybe you have UTF-8 characters in your input? It is difficult to say without the same code & input files you are using...

Comment: Another possibility: can it be that some of the strings extracted by the XML processing contain `\t` instead of spaces? That would explain extra columns in `tsv` output.

Comment: Here is an input example: https://pastebin.com/9WJf6B5v here my `tsv` code: https://pastebin.com/dTByfnPg and my `csv` code: https://pastebin.com/tTN5fvx7

Comment: The generated `tsv` is "correct" (in a sense). Did you maybe forget to disable `,` (comma) as separator when loading the document? At least LibreOffice has this option in the CSV importer dialog. Your simple TAB generator *does not* do quoting, hence `,` is unquoted and can be interpreted as column separator. Please do yourself a favor and use `my $csv = Text::CSV->new({
    binary   => 1,
    eol      => "\n",
    sep_char => "\t",
})` which generates a `tsv` with correct quoting that Libreoffice loads correctly even when TAB, comma *and* semicolon are enabled as separators.

Comment: I've added another update section to to my answer to summarize these findings.

Comment: Thank you so much! I can confirm that LibreOffice imports it as it should, only Microsoft Excel messes up the output.